# Create a slidy presentation from *Quarto*

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, slidy

Create a **slidy** presentation using R markdown is straightforward [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide. By
Yihui Xie, J. J. Allaire and Garrett Grolemund](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/slidy-presentation.html).
I try **Quarto** document (HTML format) to create such presentation (Multiple html page in one file), but horizontal rule (`---`) do not work to create a new slide/page.

Is there any way to create such presentation using **Quarto**?

Thanks

````
---
title: "Test document"
format: html
---

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```

---

You can add options to executable code like this 

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```
````

Comment: I tried with `format: slidy` and it seemed to work. Is that creating any problems for you?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I try `format: slidy`, it works for me too.